# IIS site goes hang when 100 or more users use the site

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, application-pool

I have a site in which i am using web API through ajax that hosts on same IIS as a different site and both application pool are different. My web API is in MVC4 and I am using SQL server for data access some web API takes 0 sec and some takes between 2 sec to 8 sec . My site is centralized on azure server .

My Problem is when 100 or more users uses my site my IIS web API site goes hang and not respond any request more . For this i looked worker processes, there some request listed and server was not responding any request.CPU utilization is 50% and Memory is 19 % at that time.

Can i assigned 4 worker processes to web API sites for this issue but don't know how its work if i assigned multiple work processes to one site .

If u have any idea please share with me how i handle above situation?

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to tell you what is happening without spending time with your site. There's nothing about 100 users that cause this - it has to be something in your code. Can you replicate the same issue on a different environment? Do you have any logging to identify what's happening when 100 users is exceeded?

Comment: i spent lot of time but not able to find .can u tell me ,how i can find that which query or API  hangs my site down? or deadlock issue is there....

if i do web gardening for that site that will handle if worker processes hangs or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you using an Azure VM (As from the description I see that you have access to IIS) .If that is the case,you can capture a hang dump of the process using debugdiag and do an automated analysis to figure out what is happening in your application code.

Before the issue occurs,Please go ahead and install [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) on the server

1. Capture [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924)(capture consecutive hang dumps)

   - Launch **DebugDiag Collection** and Go to the Processes tab
     [image: debugdiag process tab]
   - Reproduce the issue
   - capture a hang dump

     - right click on the w3wp.exe process
     - choose the option Create Full Memory dump
       [image: capture full memory hang dump]
   - Capture another dump after 30 seconds and then another after 30 seconds
   - You should have dumps captured in the folder C:\ProgramFiles\DebugDiag\Logs\Misc\
   - Right click on the dump file and choose the option Analyse Hang 
     [image: Analyse hang issue]

> Now the debugdiag automated hang analysis should tell you if there is any deadlock or any other issue in your code and also shows all the hung requests and where each requests are stuck.Also look at the stacktraces of the requests and see what it is doing.

Please feel free to update the question with more details if you need any help in analyzing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Yes I am using Azure VM , i will try when server hangs and will let u know

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that IIS is not causing this issue. If you think the requests are being blocked by IIS, you can check CurrentQueueSize or ActiveThreads.

You can also check executing requests from command line using 'appcmd list request' command. You will be able to see which requests are taking longer time to execute and blocking requests are usually at the top. 
There is a high-chance that something in the code is blocking the requests.

By the way, you have tagged this query under 'azure'. Are you running it as Azure Web App? If yes, you can use 'Kudu' to diagnose the cause.